# Error adding Liquidity to Uniswap V2 even though I approve tokens to router contract

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, ethers.js, uniswap

This is my controller script. I approve each token and then try to add liquidity using `addLiq` function.
I'm sure that each token is approved. However, when I call `addLiq` function, I get error.
Here is my controller script which contains two function(approve, addLiq)

```js
module.exports = {
  approve: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { token0, token1 } = req.params;
      const { amount0, amount1 } = req.body;

      const token0Contract = new ethers.Contract(
        token0,
        tokenAbi.abi,
        provider
      );
      const token1Contract = new ethers.Contract(
        token1,
        tokenAbi.abi,
        provider
      );
      const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.OWNER_PRIV, provider);
      const token0ContractWithWallet = token0Contract.connect(wallet);
      const token1ContractWithWallet = token1Contract.connect(wallet);

      //   const tx = await token0ContractWithWallet.allowance(
      //     "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266",
      //     "0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9"
      //   );
      const tx0 = await token0ContractWithWallet.approve(
        "0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9",
        amount0
      );
      const tx1 = await token1ContractWithWallet.approve(
        "0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9",
        amount1
      );

      const receipt0 = await tx0.wait();
      const receipt1 = await tx1.wait();

      res.status(200).json({
        message: "ok",
        receipt: {
          //   receipt: tx,
          receipt0: receipt0.status,
          receipt1: receipt1.status,
        },
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      res.status(500).send("internal server error");
    }
  },
  addLiq: async (req, res) => {
    const UniswapV2Router02 = new ethers.Contract(
      "0xdc64a140aa3e981100a9beca4e685f962f0cf6c9",
      Router02Abi.abi,
      provider
    );
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.OWNER_PRIV, provider);
    const UniswapV2Router02WithWallet = UniswapV2Router02.connect(wallet);
    try {
      const { token0, token1 } = req.params;
      const { amount0, amount1, amount0Min, amount1Min } = req.body;
      const tx = await UniswapV2Router02WithWallet.addLiquidity(
        token0,
        token1,
        amount0,
        amount1,
        amount0Min,
        amount1Min,
        "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266",
        {
          gasLimit: 210000,
        }
      );
      const receipt = await tx.wait();
      //   console.log(receipt);
      return res.status(200).json({
        message: "ok",
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return res.status(500).send("internal server error");
    }
  },
};
```

And i'm getting an error like this below.

```bash
reason: 'transaction failed',
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  transactionHash: '0xf7f2c946d9da692ed10191fe1b574c3446b53d738c4896aad695be28a3a1421c',
  transaction: {
    type: 2,
    chainId: 31337,
    nonce: 30,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f00', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x5c2b3424', _isBigNumber: true },
    gasPrice: null,
    gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x033450', _isBigNumber: true },
    to: '0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9',
    value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
    data: '0xca3d6539000000000000000000000000e7f1725e7734ce288f8367e1bb143e90bb3f05120000000000000000000000009fe46736679d2d9a65f0992f2272de9f3c7fa6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000271000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f40000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266',
    accessList: [],
    hash: '0xf7f2c946d9da692ed10191fe1b574c3446b53d738c4896aad695be28a3a1421c',
    v: 1,
    r: '0x72a78e60d891cc6b5e131202de2d51c5089fdd52704c2db69c8181781f0da346',
    s: '0x4130bb7964fc817b20f0ae34a46c95de4774a5f111b3a79c4717146e67579895',
    from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
    confirmations: 0,
    wait: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  receipt: {
    to: '0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9',
    from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
    contractAddress: null,
    transactionIndex: 0,
    gasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: '0x032f50', _isBigNumber: true },
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    blockHash: '0xa54a78883f980a5afe6b3b0acb1d7c5fed27b0566b296efba2967ee22267a0ce',
    transactionHash: '0xf7f2c946d9da692ed10191fe1b574c3446b53d738c4896aad695be28a3a1421c',
    logs: [],
    blockNumber: 31,
    confirmations: 1,
    cumulativeGasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: '0x032f50', _isBigNumber: true },
    effectiveGasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x5a9e1ea8', _isBigNumber: true },
    status: 0,
    type: 2,
    byzantium: true
  }
}
```

And my local blockchain network 'anvil' give this error message.

```bash
    Transaction: 0xf7f2c946d9da692ed10191fe1b574c3446b53d738c4896aad695be28a3a1421c
    Gas used: 208720
    Error: reverted with custom error: 

    Block Number: 31
    Block Hash: 0xa54a78883f980a5afe6b3b0acb1d7c5fed27b0566b296efba2967ee22267a0ce
    Block Time: "Thu, 15 Jun 2023 05:40:25 +0000"
```